# Reducing Time Complexity of algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, pseudocode

This is my pseudo code, I want to reduce the time complexity of this code. I am new to Java and algorithms. please help me in this.

```
Func1(int n, int W[1..n, 1..n]) 
{
array d[1..n, 1..n]
for i = 1 to n do 
{ // initialize
    for j = 1 to n do {
        d[i,j] = W[i,j]
        pred[i,j] = null
    }
}
for k = 1 to n do // use intermediates {1..k}
for i = 1 to n do // ...from i
for j = 1 to n do // ...to j
if (d[i,k] + d[k,j]) < d[i,j]) 
{
    d[i,j] = d[i,k] + d[k,j] // new shorter path length
    pred[i,j] = k // new path is through k
}
return d // matrix of final distances
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the Floyd-Warshall algorithm for All Pairs Shortest Paths. It's O(V^3), and you're not going to make it faster than O(V^3). For sparse graphs, Dijkstra's algorithm may be faster. (For dense graphs, it will be slower.)